# Check if $_GET variable contains letters

Tags: php, get

I have one `$_GET` variable named `page` which can contain only numbers. So far I managed to make the other rules like if it's empty to force the page to be equal to 1 or if it's bigger than the total number of pages to bring an error message, but one thing i can't do is make it so that when a user types a letter instead of a number like: `page=d`; to receive an error message.

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

Comment: do some google before ask

Comment: You can make use `js` when user types or you can use `is_numeric` function of php as suggested by @Felix Kling

Comment: you are trying to invent the wheel

Comment: [filter_input](http://php.net/filter_input) would be a good start.

Comment: Googling first would have made this so much easier for you!

Answer (score 6):

Using `is_numeric` will allow hexadecimal numbers to slip through. To allow only [0-9], you can use:

```
if (!ctype_digit($_GET['page'])) {
    // Error message here.
}
```

Remember to also make sure that `$_GET['page']` is set.

Comment: This is the best bet to me, as it will catch all other variations of the variable $_GET['page'] only allowing for [0-9] integers.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_GET['page']) && preg_match('/^\d+$/', $_GET['page'])){
    echo 'only numbers';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
function isNumberKey(evt)
      {
         var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
         if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;

         return true;
      }
```